# Why does print('\x9f') in the python3 REPL hang gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, python3, unicode, xterm

xterm doesn't hang. echo -e '\x9f' doesn't hang on xterm or gnome terminal.
non-REPL python3 (3.6, 3.8, 3.9 tried) truncates the string but doesn't hang. Same for IPython 7.13.0

Gnome Terminal version is 3.36.2

So what's going on? I couldn't find a bug for Python or Gnome Terminal that relate to this in their bug trackers.

Answer (score 0):

python3's `print('\x9f')` prints the UTF-8 encoded version of the U+009F character (assuming that your locale is set to UTF-8, which is a pretty reasonable assumption). This is not the same as the single 0x9F byte printed by `echo -e '\x9f'`, which is invalid UTF-8.

U+0080 .. U+009F are control characters, potentially causing subsequent data to be interpreted as parameters, rather than letters to be displayed. Some terminal emulators (e.g. gnome-terminal) support these control characters even in UTF-8, while some others (e.g. xterm) reject them in UTF-8 and only recognize their 7-bit-clean counterparts in this encoding. Which one is correct is probably debatable.

The bottom line is: Never print something to the terminal that isn't printable (according to `iswprint()` or its equivalent), unless you know exactly what you're doing (e.g. your explicit intent is to print an escape sequence). And stick to the 7-bit-clean C0 control codes rather than the problematic C1 ones.